# При введении цифр в строку, отобразить её в виде вывода цифр калькулятора

Tags: swift3, swift4

При введении цифр в строку отобразить её в виде вывода цифр калькулятора. Исключается вид вывода ,934,432. Как можно еще реализовать данное задание исключив вывод встроенным методом NSFormatter и аналогичных? Спасибо.

```
    let newNumbers = makeNumber(number: "1234567894")
    print(newNumbers)

}
func makeNumber(number: String) -> String {
    let reversed = String(number.reversed())
    var newText = ""
    for (index, character) in reversed.enumerated() {
        if index != 0 && index % 3 == 0 {
            newText.append(",")
        }
        newText.append(String(character))

    }
    return String(newText.reversed())
```

При вводе цифр number: `"1234567894"` на выходе получаем `1,234,567,894`. Исключается на выходе `,234,567,894` если введено `234567894`. Вставить запятые с зада на перед отделяя по 3 символа, как это выводится в калькуляторе.

Comment: Объясните подробнее, не совсем понятно что Вы хотите.

Comment: При вводе цифр number: "1234567894" на выходе получаем 1,234,567,894. Исключается на выходе ,234,567,894 если введено 234567894. Вставить запятые с зада на перед отделяя по 3 символа, как это выводится в калькуляторе.

Answer (score 1):

NSNumberFormatter конечно лучше всего. Но если хотите вручуню.
Со строкой будет много кода и не совсем красиво. Можете с числом сделать:

```
let number = 12345678
print(getNumberComponents(number).joined(separator: "'"))

func getNumberComponents(_ number: Int, arr: [String] = []) -> [String] {
    guard number != 0 else {
        return arr
    }
    return getNumberComponents(number / 1000, arr: ([String(number % 1000)] + arr))
}

// MARK: - Strings

func getStridesArray(from text: String) -> [String] {
    var result: [String] = []
    let characters = Array(text)
    stride(from: characters.count, through: 0, by: -3).forEach {
        result.append(String(characters[max($0-3, 0)..<$0]))
    }
    return result.reversed()
}
print(getStridesArray(from: "12345678").joined(separator: "'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"(.)(?=(...)+$)", "\\1,", x)
```

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/MnX4LE

```
import re

try:
  while True:
    x = input()
    print(re.sub(r"(.)(?=(...)+$)", "\\1,", x))
except (EOFError):
  pass
```